# Where do I put my website configuration values in a LAMP server setup?

Tags: php, apache, configuration, webserver, lamp

I have usually put database and website-specific configuration values into global variables within a .php file. This gets included into any page that needs to access the database.

Is there anywhere more sensible that these things should go? Can I add arbitrary values to php.ini, and if so how? Or how about http.conf in apache? Can I configure my website that way?

Ideally, I'd like a solution that means the config isn't being read on every single request.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out a better way through fiddling around. You can add arbitrary config options to php.ini, e.g.

```
[MyGreatWebsite]
dbname=db_awesome
```

And you can retrieve them with the `get_cfg_var` function, e.g.

```
get_cfg_var('dbname')
```

It's not exposing things through phpinfo (As an env variable would) and it's only reading the config once (Verifiable because changing the values requires a server restart)

Comment: Why bad? And why worse than the existing mysql.default_host in the same file?

Answer (score 2):

My experience says, that easiest way is the best way, so I would put the database connection conf in a file which is *part of the project*. Why? Because:

- Each project has, or should have, configuration file/files (INI, XML, JSON....)
- Global variables r currently overkill and dead
- If somebody would like to find where to change the config for the database, Apache files would be **last** place they should check!

My advice on a simple solution for you is to create a file, like Config.php, and put a class inside it which loads an XML, INI or another type of file with structural data. And then by calling **getters** you can fetch your config whenever and wherever you want.

Comment: I'm kinda looking for something where the config gets read once, and not on every single page request

Answer (score 1):

In Apache you can use `SetEnv`

```
SetEnv NAME value
```

Which will be accessible with `$_SERVER['NAME']`

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html

With PHP you can set default MySQL connection settings in the INI

```
mysql.default_host = ...
mysql.default_user = ...
mysql.default_password = ...
```

or

```
mysqli.default_host = ...
mysqli.default_user = ...
mysqli.default_password = ...
```

Comment: I like this idea, and thanks for the heads up on the default connection values. I am slightly worried about accidentally exposing a database password this way with a careless phpinfo

Comment: @izb shouldn't really matter too much if the password was exposed. As long as the password is unique, and only allowed connections from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your data as environment values in Apache, as Petah pointed out, via SetEnv.

You are not gaining anything however security wise, it's more a matter of preferences (and don't forget that than you must not show your environment variables via such things as phpinfo() ).

The other common way, as you said, is to hold your config variables in a file outside of the documentroot so that it cannot be accessed by a browser, and ensure your code doesn't read and show his content to other eyes.

I do not think there are extravagant cool ways to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Storing DB Credentials

I strongly recommend using INI in combination with `SetEnv` in your .htaccess file.  As others have already stated.

### Object Persistence

However, if you want to avoid having to load this data for every request then you would need some sort of object persistence.  For instance, Doctrine or MongoDB or *both*. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4081150/486233

[object persistence in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251861/object-persistence-in-php)

Comment: Personally, I like the simplicity of using MongoDB solo but Doctrine is fantastic!